# Android error: Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: java, android, eclipse, software-packaging, system.io.packaging

I have been having this problem on Eclipse lately. Whenever I build a project, this error comes up:

```
Android error: Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\me\workspace\project\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist    Android Packaging Problem.
```

I have been searching the web, and I have found multiple answers; however, these do not seem to work. I have tried searching for a "debug.keystore" file, but have not found one. I have cleaned and built the project multiple times, and still have no luck.

A quick answer to this problem would be appreciated. I can post any code or answer and questions you might have about the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like just closing and opening the project again refreshes the build error. Hopefully this will work for anyone else out there having this problem.